# Breaking the 7zip test function once password returns true

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I would like to test the .7zips found within a directory against the password that's provided by the user. Currently the t switch causes 7zip to test the entire archive in depth, and I would like it to break once the password returns true.

```
$CaseDirectory = Read-Host 'Please input Case directory'
$Password = Read-Host 'Please input Case password'

$7ZipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $CaseDirectory -Recurse -Force -Filter *.7z

$Output = Foreach ($File in $Files)
{
& $7ZipPath "t" $File.FullName "-p$Password"
if (-not $?)
{  
   Write-Output $File "Wrong Password!"
} else {
    Write-Output $File "Password Match"
}
Write-Output "================================================================"
Write-Host "Working.."


} 
$Output | findstr /r /v "^$" | Out-File -FilePath 
$CaseDirectory\PasswordTest_Output.txt 

pause
```

Comment: Does changing `"t"` to `"-t"` resolve the issue?

Comment: Apparently, the `-t` is something totally different. `-t` specifies the type of archive and is a _switch_. There is also the _command_ `t` which tests the integrity of the archive. Found this [here](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/index.htm)